# Combining ORDER BY FIELD and another query

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I would like to combine two queries (that currently run separately). For example: I would like to get info of 100 products that in stock, but top 10 will be the most sold items (stored in another table).

I'm trying to do something like that:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `products`
WHERE `inStock` = 1
ORDER BY FIELD(id, (
    SELECT `productId` 
    FROM `sold_items` 
    ORDER BY `count` DESC
    LIMIT 10
))
LIMIT 100
```

Is it possible to do it with only one query?

Comment: FIELD is not applicable to rowset, it needs separate literals.

Answer (score 0):

You can join the table `products` with a `LEFT` join to this query:

```
SELECT * FROM sold_items ORDER BY `count` DESC LIMIT 10
```

and sort the resultset by the column count descending:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM sold_items ORDER BY `count` DESC LIMIT 10) s
ON s.productId = p.id
WHERE p.inStock = 1
ORDER BY COALESCE(s.count, 0) DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

This way only the top 10 sold products will be sorted at the top and for all the others the sort order is not defined.